# Set security flag On for firefox, chorme and IE webdriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, selenium, firefox

I am using selenium with Java and I want to set below security option set as On for firefox.
[firefox security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYDih.jpg)

Below is the code which I am using to set the security option On.

```
profile.setPreference("browser.safebrowsing.enabled",true);
profile.setPreference("browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled", true);
```

It give error message like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Preference browser.safebrowsing.enabled may not be overridden: frozen value=false, requested value=true
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:146)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.checkPreference(Preferences.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.setPreference(Preferences.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.java:247)
    at crossbrowser.browsertest.main(browsertest.java:30)
```

Can anyone please let me know how I can resolve it and same can implement for chrome and IE browser?

Answer (score -1):

You can't, the value is frozen, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Is there any alternate way to make this settings?

Comment: If the person that downvoted my answer could provide the answer they think is correct instead that would be great, thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13526934)

Comment: @sidgate that is literally the only answer to the question. It's impossible to do what is asked..